# Register a vue store module in a router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babel-loader

i'm trying to chunk up my application better, so the specific sections are only loaded when needed. I can lazy load my normal vue components fine but i'm struggling with the store modules.

I have read i should be able to do something like this, so it loads the module before the route kicks, but i keep getting the `storeMod` as undefined.

I've seen you need to use the babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import package witch i have brought in, but my import still returns nothing.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    import('./store')
        .then(({ storeMod}) => { 
            debugger
            if (!store.state.corporate) store.registerModule('storeMod', storeMod)
        })
        .then(() => {
            next()
        })
})
```

i know the store is ok and the registerModule is working because if i bring the store module in like

`import storeModfrom './store'`

and drop that into the registerModule it works fine, but thats not putting the module into my chuck section as i would like

I think it must be to do with the way ive setup babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import but i'm not sure what. The only difference i can see is most of the examples are using the @babel packages are we aren't

Cheers

Comment: Your check doesn't match your import. If you don't explicitly export something named `storeMod` you probably need to avoid destructuring : `then(( storeMod )`